# Can you tell if a photo was shot on Medium Format by looking at the result?

Tags: medium-format

Sometimes I see some photos that look so good!

Is it a matter of training the eyes to know if something is shot on Medium Format?

For example these:
http://monrowemagazine.com/2018/01/15/dream-of-blisters/

Are there some things that you can look for in a photo and know that *oh yes they shot this on a gooood camera!*?

Comment: Certain films are killer in 120. For me, Delta3200 is sooo much better in 120 - and I'm pretty sure I could call it when I see it. Outside of that though...well, I'm lookin' forward to what others say. :-)

Comment: @MichaelClark Do we have an existing question that you have in mind? Maybe [Is there a “special look” to images from large sensors that can't be replicated with a smaller one?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/60432/is-there-a-special-look-to-images-from-large-sensors-that-cant-be-replicated/60435#60435), although that is somewhat more narrow.

Comment: That one plus [How can these photos by Martin Schoeller have such a high quality?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/9421/15871) and [Why invest in high end large- and medium-format digital cameras?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/11291/15871) and [How do I give my images this vintage travel photo effect?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/73706/15871)

Answer (score 1):

There are obviously differences between Full-Frame and Medium Format, otherwise people would not be paying so much more just for a heavier camera.

Those who know can recognise the difference but that depends on the photo and most importantly the size at which it is viewed. In theory, one of the main difference is depth-of-field but since lenses are not the same on both for types of camera, you often have access to wider apertures on full-frame than on medium format, which cancels out much of the differnce.

The one difference that really stands out to my eyes is dynamic-range. I have shot architecture around me with Medium Format, Full-Frame, APS-C, Four-Thirds and even smaller sensor, so I have a good amount of images that I can directly compare. The Fujifilm GFX 50S for example captures such high dynamic-range that its outputs looks very similar to properly-done HDR.

Resolution is also very high on Medium Format, although the difference between Full-Frame is not that much. There are full-frame cameras with virtually the same resolution as Medium Format ones. This is mostly visible on very large prints but even when resolution is nearly the same, Medium Format will produce better pixels with lower-noise, more dynamic-range and refined colors. Again, this will not be noticeable on any image but it will on some.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much impossible to say for certain something is Medium Format rather than a full frame, or even a crop sensor...It really boils down to how easy it is to get really great dept of field quality.
This image for instance...https://shardy.smugmug.com/Linnette-December/i-f5F5Cr4/A
Could be any of he 3, but you must use a smaller DOF to get the same effect, the smaller the sensor....Oh and just better glass with fewer elements ;)